# Simple Vertex Shader for color based on model space vertex Z coord

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, vertex-shader

I have a simple function map_color that computes the color of vertexes for an erosion simulator at my University. I would like to convert this to a vertex shader. It seems simple enough for my first shader but I don't know where to start. I've seen a couple of code samples that seem promising but are overly complicated and hard for me to follow.

I should mention that I'm using java/jogl but I can look up the details of loading the shader and turning it on myself. Mostly looking for help with the actual shader code.

```
private void map_color(float height, float color[])
    {

        float t = (height - COLOR_MIN_HEIGHT) / (COLOR_MAX_HEIGHT - COLOR_MIN_HEIGHT);

        // Clamp to range, just in case
        if(t < 0.0) t = 0.0f;
        if(t > 1.0) t = 1.0f;

        // Brown yellow map
        if (t < 0.5)
        {
            color[0] = 0.488f + t * 0.836f;
            color[1] = 0.164f + t * 0.953f;
            color[2] = 0.094f + t * 0.172f;
        }
        else
        {
            color[0] = 0.906f + (t - 0.5f) * 0.180f;
            color[1] = 0.640f + (t - 0.5f) * 0.680f;
            color[2] = 0.180f + (t - 0.5f) * 0.773f;
        }

    }
    private void drawTerrain()
        {
            // Need a separate vertex normal for each quad -- this implementation is inefficient
            // Should be computed once and stored when grid is loaded

        float [] v1 = new float[3];
        float [] v2 = new float[3];
        float [] norm = new float[3];
        float [] color = new float[3];

        v1[0] = gridHorizontalScaleFactor / 5.0f;  // Scale factor is a hack
        v1[1] = 0.0f;

        v2[0] = 0.0f;
        v2[1] = gridHorizontalScaleFactor / 5.0f;  // Ditto on hack

        // Get ready for varying material properties
        gl.glEnable(GLLightingFunc.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        gl.glColorMaterial(GL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,
                GLLightingFunc.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);

        for(int x = 2; x < latticeSizeX-1; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 2; y < latticeSizeY-1; y++)
            {
                gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
                v1[2] = unsafeTopo.getFloatAt((x+1) * 263 + y) - unsafeTopo.getFloatAt( (x-1) * 263 + y);
                v2[2] = unsafeTopo.getFloatAt(x * 263 + (y + 1)) - unsafeTopo.getFloatAt( x * 263 + (y - 1));

                cross(norm, v2, v1);

                gl.glNormal3fv(norm, 0);

                map_color(unsafeTopo.getFloatAt(x * 263 + y), color);
                gl.glColor3f(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
                gl.glVertex3f(x,   y,   unsafeTopo.getFloatAt(x * 263 + y));

                map_color(unsafeTopo.getFloatAt((x+1) * 263 + y), color);
                gl.glColor3f(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
                gl.glVertex3f(x+1, y,   unsafeTopo.getFloatAt((x+1) * 263 + y));

                map_color(unsafeTopo.getFloatAt(x * 263 + (y + 1)), color);
                gl.glColor3f(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
                gl.glVertex3f(x,   y+1, unsafeTopo.getFloatAt(x * 263 + (y + 1)));

                v1[2] = unsafeTopo.getFloatAt((x+2) * 263 + y+1) - unsafeTopo.getFloatAt(x * 263 + (y + 1));
                v2[2] = unsafeTopo.getFloatAt((x+1) * 263 + y+2) - unsafeTopo.getFloatAt((x+1) * 263 + y);

                cross(norm, v2, v1);

                map_color(unsafeTopo.getFloatAt((x+1) * 263 + y+1), color);
                gl.glColor3f(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
                gl.glVertex3f(x+1, y+1, unsafeTopo.getFloatAt((x+1) * 263 + y+1));

                map_color(unsafeTopo.getFloatAt(x * 263 + (y + 1)), color);
                gl.glColor3f(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
                gl.glVertex3f(x,   y+1, unsafeTopo.getFloatAt(x * 263 + (y + 1)));

                map_color(unsafeTopo.getFloatAt((x+1) * 263 + y), color);
                gl.glColor3f(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
                gl.glVertex3f(x+1, y,   unsafeTopo.getFloatAt((x+1) * 263 + y));

                gl.glEnd();
            }
        }
        gl.glDisable(GLLightingFunc.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at our simple examples in jogl-demos on Github?

Comment: yes I tried to integrate one of the jogl demos. specifically this one https://github.com/xranby/jogl/blob/master/src/test/com/jogamp/opengl/test/junit/jogl/demos/es2/RedSquareES2.java I first just tried to make each poly red but they just show up black which means the shader didnt get applied

Comment: The author of this example (Xerxes alias xranby) is on StackOverflow but you should contact it on our IRC channel or on our official forum: http://forum.jogamp.org/ Please post your whole code on our forum. What happens when you run the demo without any change?

Comment: well i just tried to pull the whole project down from git but it complains it can't find ant and swt so I can't build it right now. going to try again in the morning

Comment: You need to get the projects GlueGen, JOAL and JOGL too to make it work. Please follow our instructions: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Build

Comment: Hi @Aaron, you should avoid legacy OpenGL